# How to fix dual monitor disconnect after desktop boot on Linux Mint 17 Xfce?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

When I boot into my desktop, my dual monitors go into power save mode and the communication between the monitors and the graphics card radeon x1650 is disabled? When I press `ctrl+F2` or `ctrl+F7` I receive the following message :

```
mei_me 0000:00:03.0 : timer: connect/disconnect timeout.
```

When I use `ctrl+F7` I can see the mouse, but I cannot move the mouse. The screen is black with the `mei_me` error posted at the top left of the screen.

Further testing of the problem is given below:

Re-installing Linux Mint 17 Xfce did not solve the problem. Booting into my desktop with two monitors plugged in disables them. Trying different settings on the `xfce-display-settings` before and after the reboot does not change the problem. The problem can be temporarily fixed when I `ctrl+F2` and `startx` and I can dual monitor after. A single monitor works fine on boot and then I can dual monitor after. I cannot dual monitor boot without the both monitors disabling after desktop loads.

How do I fix dual monitor disconnect after desktop boot on Linux Mint 17 Xfce?

Comment: `mei_me` is the _Intel Management Engine Interface_, you can disable that in the BIOS / UEFI or blacklist the module. I don't think it's related though.